# The area of the triangle formed by the coordinate axes and tangent at vertex to the parabola whose focus is $(3,4)$

Tags: conic-sections

The area of the triangle formed by the coordinate axes and tangent at vertex to the parabola whose focus is $(3,4)$ and tangents at $x=0$ and $y=0$ is?

I know how to do this, assume an equation for parabola with axis as $y=4/3 x$ and do all the procedure. But, this isn't how it is really to be solved. There's a sleek way which I cannot find.

Comment: This question is not well posed.  There exist an infinite number of parabolas with focus at (3, 4).  More information is needed.  And "y= 4/3x" is NOT a parabola.   A parabola with vertical line of symmetry can be written as $y= a(x- h)^2+ k$ and has focus $\left(h, k+ \frac{1}{4a}\right)$.  Saying that the focus is at (3, 4) means h= 3 and $k+ \frac{1}{4a}= 4$ so $k= 4-\frac{1}{4a}$.  A parabola of the form $y= a(x- 3)^2+ 4- \frac{1}{4a}$, for any a, has focus (3, 4).

Comment: @user247327 No, the parabola _has_ x=y=0 as tangents. Also, $y=4/3x$ is axis of the parabola.

Comment: How do you know that the parabola’s axis passes through the origin as you claim with that equation of the axis?

Answer (score 5):

A [nice property of the parabola](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/665837/prove-that-the-foot-of-the-perpendicular-from-the-focus-to-any-tangent-of-a-para/3060866#3060866) states that: the perpendicular from the focus to any tangent intersects it, and the tangent through the vertex, at the same point.

Hence the tangent at the vertex intersects the axes at $(3,0)$ and $(0,4)$.

[image]